# Elasticsearch 7.10.0 is throwing Exception

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a custom Elastic plugin for Elasticsearch 7.10.0, that calculates score of each record and if there is no record that meets minimum score threshold, it returns topDocs.scoreDocs with no element.
but it seems elastic internals is throwing array_index_out_of_bounds_exception. Plugin is using org.elasticsearch.search.rescore.Rescorer.rescore

> {
> "took": 9,
> "timed_out": false,
> "_shards": {
> "total": 4,
> "successful": 3,
> "skipped": 0,
> "failed": 1,
> "failures": [
> {
> "shard": 2,
> "index": "elastic-index",
> "node": "esUKw65ARD2wewewewee",
> "reason": {
> "type": "array_index_out_of_bounds_exception",
> "reason": "Index 0 out of bounds for length 0"
> }
> }
> ]
> },
> "hits": {
> "total": {
> "value": 0,
> "relation": "eq"
> },
> "max_score": null,
> "hits": []
> }
> }

is there any way to avoid this exception?

Comment: Could you add `error_trace` parameter to your query and run it again to see where this error originates?

Comment: Hi, GET /my-index/_search?error_trace=true is giving me exact same details no further information to relate.

Comment: Is there anything in the logs around the time this exception occurs?